# How i can set custom breakpoint for responsive toggle menu in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, toggle

How to set custom breakpoint for responsive toggle menu in bootstrap 4 when i will set example 1200 breakpoint than my toggle menu appear when my screen size less than 1200 width. i want breakpoint when i enter any size of screen set toggle menu. any buddy have example please give me.

**Note please attachment bootstrap 4 js than try.**

```css
header .navbar {
      background-color: #000;
    }
    header .navbar-light .navbar-brand {
      color: #fff;
    }
    header .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      color: #fff;
    }
    header .navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: you have to use `media-query`

Comment: i have no more idea about breakpoint so can not use media query

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a breakpoint you should use @media query, for exmaple:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    header .navbar {
      background-color: #000;
    }
    header .navbar-light .navbar-brand {
      color: #fff;
    }
    header .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      color: #fff;
    }
    header .navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
}
```

this will only toggle if your screen is  less than or equal to 1200px,

## or

if you want to be more specific about breakpoint:

```
   @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
//this will only toggle if your screen is between 1200px and 767px
    }
```

Comment: no suppose i use @media query of 1200 than appear mobile toggle in 1200 width scree?

Comment: try to use @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {}, for me mobile breakpoint starts at 767px upto 320px

Comment: i know @media but which css i set for block toggle into our custome css?

Comment: maybe we are not clear on about what you want to achieve with regards to breakpoints can you clearly state again your problem?

Comment: i want mobile menu in desktop means toggle i want in desktop

Comment: yeah i switch toggle in to desktop but i don't know how it possible so

Comment: I have posted a new answer maybe that will solve it.

Comment: possible less than 1200 width device? only toggle display less than 1200 width device?

Comment: How ? Let me know

Comment: you may really customize the assets of bootstrap. try it yourslef

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the answer to your question. no need to customize the main assets, just use the external content(collapsible navbar) for bootstrap

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fzb07qsd/

## HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="pos-f-t">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
        
  </nav>
     <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
                     <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```